# How to write a C program that, when invoked, runs another given program and attempts to control behaviors of the child process

Tags: c, linux

Good afternoon, My objective is to write a C program that, when invoked, runs another given program and attempts to control behaviors of the child process.

If the child opens any file (other than the pre-opened files stdin, stdout, stderr), this should be prevented and the program should be terminated.

I wrote the following program to implement the above program requiremnents. The good news is my program consistently intercepts SIGIO signals generated when the  child opens any file (other than the pre-opened files stdin, stdout, stderr) only when my program is run after I have restarted the LINUX OS from a KITTY session.
   The problem is that after the first time my program is run successfully, it fails on subsequent attempts to intercept SIGIO signals. Please tell me what I am doing wrong in my program and how I might fix it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <sys/sysinfo.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <sys/ptrace.h>

#define MAXLINE 256
#define MAXARGS 128
#define SHELL   "/h/fchang03" 
#define READ 0
#define WRITE 1

pthread_mutex_t mut = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
int fd[2];
pthread_spinlock_t spinlock;

struct statStuff {
    int pid;                    // %d 
    char comm[256];             // %s
    char state;                 // %c
    int ppid;                   // %d
    int pgrp;                   // %d
    int session;                // %d
    int tty_nr;                 // %d
    int tpgid;                  // %d
    unsigned long flags;        // %lu
    unsigned long minflt;       // %lu
    unsigned long cminflt;      // %lu
    unsigned long majflt;       // %lu
    unsigned long cmajflt;      // %lu
    unsigned long utime;        // %lu
    unsigned long stime;        // %lu
    long cutime;                // %ld
    long cstime;                // %ld
    long priority;              // %ld
    long nice;                  // %ld
    long num_threads;           // %ld
    long itrealvalue;           // %ld
    unsigned long starttime;    // %lu
    unsigned long vsize;        // %lu
    long rss;                   // %ld
    unsigned long rlim;         // %lu
    unsigned long startcode;    // %lu
    unsigned long endcode;      // %lu
    unsigned long startstack;   // %lu
    unsigned long kstkesp;      // %lu
    unsigned long kstkeip;      // %lu
    unsigned long signal;       // %lu
    unsigned long blocked;      // %lu
    unsigned long sigignore;    // %lu
    unsigned long sigcatch;     // %lu
    unsigned long wchan;        // %lu
    unsigned long nswap;        // %lu
    unsigned long cnswap;       // %lu
    int exit_signal;            // %d
    int processor;              // %d
    unsigned long rt_priority;  // %lu 
    unsigned long policy;       // %lu 
    unsigned long long delayacct_blkio_ticks;   // %llu 
} ;

static int readStat(int pid, struct statStuff *s) {

    const char *format = "%d %s %c %d %d %d %d %d %lu %lu %lu %lu %lu %lu %lu %ld %ld %ld %ld %ld %ld %lu %lu %ld %lu %lu %lu %lu %lu %lu %lu %lu %lu %lu %lu %lu %lu %d %d %lu %lu %llu";

    char buf[256];
    FILE *proc;
    sprintf(buf,"/proc/%d/stat",pid);
    proc = fopen(buf,"r");
    if (proc) {
        if (42==fscanf(proc, format,
            &s->pid,
            s->comm,
            &s->state,
            &s->ppid,
            &s->pgrp,
            &s->session,
            &s->tty_nr,
            &s->tpgid,
            &s->flags,
            &s->minflt,
            &s->cminflt,
            &s->majflt,
            &s->cmajflt,
            &s->utime,
            &s->stime,
            &s->cutime,
            &s->cstime,
            &s->priority,
            &s->nice,
            &s->num_threads,
            &s->itrealvalue,
            &s->starttime,
            &s->vsize,
            &s->rss,
            &s->rlim,
            &s->startcode,
            &s->endcode,
            &s->startstack,
            &s->kstkesp,
            &s->kstkeip,
            &s->signal,
            &s->blocked,
            &s->sigignore,
            &s->sigcatch,
            &s->wchan,
            &s->nswap,
            &s->cnswap,
            &s->exit_signal,
            &s->processor,
            &s->rt_priority,
            &s->policy,
            &s->delayacct_blkio_ticks
        )) {
       printf("Group Number = %d\n",s->session);
       printf("Stack start = %x\n",s->startstack);
       printf("Stack end = %x\n",s->kstkesp);   
           fclose(proc);
           return s->session;
        } else {
           fclose(proc);
           return 0;
        }
     } else {
        return 0;
     }
}



int eval(const char *cmdline)
{
    char *argv[MAXARGS];
        int bg;
        pid_t pid;
        int status;
        struct statStuff test;
    int value;
    FILE* fp; 
        struct rusage usage; 

        pid = fork();
        if (pid > 0){ 
              /* This is the child process. */
              char* p;
              int num_procs;
              int n_bytes = 256;
              int bytes_read;
              char buffer[1024];    
              char stuff[256];          
              char* ptr;
                  struct rlimit rl;
              int x;

                      sscanf(cmdline,"%s %d",stuff,&x); 
              rl.rlim_cur = 15; 
              rl.rlim_max = 15;
                  setrlimit(RLIMIT_NPROC,&rl);      
                  ptr = 0;          
              if (x == 0){
                        sprintf(buffer,"/proc/%d/stat",pid); 
              }
              else{
            sprintf(buffer,"/proc/%d/stat",x);
                  }
              int fd  = open(buffer,O_RDONLY);
              while (read(fd,buffer,256) > 0){
                sprintf(cmdline,"%s %d",stuff,readStat(x,&test));
                printf("CMDLINE = %s\n",cmdline);
                eval(cmdline);
                            lseek(fd,256,SEEK_CUR);

              }   
                      close(fd);                      
                      wait3(&status,0,&usage);
              exit(1);  
          }
          else if (pid < 0){
              /* The fork failed. Report failure. */
              status = -1;  
          }
          else{
                      close(fd[READ]); 
                      close(fileno(stdout)); 
                  dup(fd[WRITE]);
                      fcntl(0,F_SETFL,O_ASYNC);
                      fcntl(1,F_SETFL,O_ASYNC);
                      fcntl(2,F_SETFL,O_ASYNC);
                      fcntl(3,F_SETFL,O_ASYNC);
              execl("/h/fchang03/five","five",0);
              perror("execl");             
              }
       return 0;    
}

void *reader(int signal)
{
    pid_t pid1,pid2;
    int status; 
    int fd[2];
    char buf[256];
    char buffer[256];   
    char filename[256];
    char dbgfilename[256];
    int myfd;
    int length;
    struct rusage usage;        

//    printf("SIGNAl  %d received\n",signal);
    printf("%s","                   ");

    length = 256;
    if (signal == 0){
    return NULL;
    }   

    pipe(fd);
    if ((pid1 = fork())) { /* child subprocess */ 
        pthread_spin_lock(&spinlock);
        sprintf(filename,"/proc/%d/fdinfo/1",pid1);
        myfd = open(filename,O_RDONLY);
        pthread_spin_unlock(&spinlock);
        if (myfd == -1){
                    printf("myfd = %d filename = %s\n",myfd,filename);
                        perror("myerror");
            exit(1);
        }
        fcntl(0,F_SETOWN,getpid());
                fcntl(1,F_SETOWN,getpid());
                fcntl(2,F_SETOWN,getpid());
        fcntl(3,F_SETOWN,getpid());
        if (signal == SIGIO){
            printf("SIGNAL SIGIO RECEIVED");
            kill(pid1,SIGKILL); 
        }
                close(myfd);
        close(fd[WRITE]);
            FILE *read = fdopen(fd[READ],"r");
            while (!feof(read)) {
                fgets(buf,256,read);
            }
        close(fd[READ]);
            pid2 = wait3(&status,0, &usage);
        if (signal == SIGKILL){
            exit(1);
        }
   }
   else {
        close(fd[READ]);
            close(fileno(stdout));
            dup(fd[WRITE]);
                //  child only unblock mask

                fcntl(0, F_SETFL, O_ASYNC);
        fcntl(1, F_SETFL, O_ASYNC);
        fcntl(2, F_SETFL, O_ASYNC);
        fcntl(3, F_SETFL, O_ASYNC);

                execl("/h/fchang03/five","five",NULL);

  }

}

int main(void)
{
     pthread_t tid1,tid2;
     char cmdline[MAXLINE];
     char temp[MAXLINE];    
     int start;

     struct sigaction set,myset;

     pthread_t thread;
     pthread_t thread2;

     sigemptyset(&set);
     sigemptyset(&myset);   
     memset(&set,0,sizeof(struct sigaction));
     memset(&myset,0,sizeof(struct sigaction));
     sigaddset(&set.sa_mask, SIGINT);
     sigaddset(&set.sa_mask, SIGCHLD);
     sigaddset(&set.sa_mask, SIGIO); 
     set.sa_flags = SA_RESTART | SA_NOCLDSTOP | SA_SIGINFO;
     set.sa_handler = reader;  

     sigaddset(&myset.sa_mask, SIGIO);       
     myset.sa_flags = SA_RESTART | SA_NOCLDSTOP | SA_SIGINFO;
     myset.sa_handler  = reader;  

     sigprocmask(SIG_UNBLOCK, &myset, &set); // later explicitly just unblock SIGIO 
     sigaction(SIGCHLD,&myset,&set);    
     sigaction(SIGIO,&myset,&set);

     pthread_spin_init(&spinlock, 0);
     pthread_create(&tid1,NULL,reader,NULL);
     pthread_create(&tid2,NULL,reader,NULL);

     pthread_join(tid1,NULL);
     pthread_join(tid2,NULL);


     start = 0; 
     while (1){
          printf("> ");
          fgets(temp, MAXLINE, stdin);
          sprintf(cmdline,"./%s %d",temp,start);
              if (feof(stdin)){
                 exit(0);   
              }
          if (eval(cmdline) == -1){
              break;
          }     
     }  

}
```

Comment: What's wrong with redirecting I/O for the child process to /dev/null?

Comment: @Jon Trauntvein, Please tell me where I am redirecting I/O  for the child process to /dev/null. Thanks, Frank

Answer (score 0):

When I modify the signal handler and thread functor function, reader, I can now intercept the SIGIO and associated SIGCHLD signal every time. Thanks, Frank

```
void *reader(int signal)
{
    pid_t pid1,pid2;
    int status;
    int fd[2];
    char buf[256];
    char buffer[256];
    char filename[256];
    char dbgfilename[256];
    int myfd;
    int length;
    struct rusage usage;

//    printf("SIGNAl  %d received\n",signal);
    printf("%s","                   ");

    length = 256;
    if (signal == 0){
        return NULL;
    }

    pipe(fd);
    if ((pid1 = fork())) { /* child subprocess */
                pthread_spin_lock(&spinlock);
                sprintf(filename,"/proc/%d/fdinfo/1",pid1);
                myfd = open(filename,O_RDONLY);
                pthread_spin_unlock(&spinlock);
                if (myfd == -1){
                        printf("myfd = %d filename = %s\n",myfd,filename);
                        perror("myerror");
                        exit(1);
                }
                fcntl(0,F_SETOWN,getpid());
                fcntl(1,F_SETOWN,getpid());
                fcntl(2,F_SETOWN,getpid());
                fcntl(3,F_SETOWN,getpid());
                if (signal == SIGIO || signal == SIGCHLD){
                        printf("SIGNAL SIGIO RECEIVED");
                        kill(pid1,SIGKILL);
                }
                close(myfd);
      close(fd[WRITE]);
                FILE *read = fdopen(fd[READ],"r");
                while (!feof(read)) {
                        fgets(buf,256,read);
                }
                close(fd[READ]);
                pid2 = wait3(&status,0, &usage);
                exit(1);
   }
   else {
                close(fd[READ]);
                close(fileno(stdout));
                dup(fd[WRITE]);
                //  child only unblock mask

                fcntl(0, F_SETFL, O_ASYNC);
                fcntl(1, F_SETFL, O_ASYNC);
                fcntl(2, F_SETFL, O_ASYNC);
                fcntl(3, F_SETFL, O_ASYNC);

                execl("/h/fchang03/five","five",NULL);

  }
}
```